# Doctrine2 and inheritance

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, dql

I have a model with inheritance.

Abstract class X,

With subclasses A, B and C...

In my form people need to be able to select what type of X is applying, depending on this choice the form will show A's, B's or C's...

How do I ask X what types it has?

I thought by using a distinct select on the discriminator, but didn't manage..

Any ideas?

It would be OK, if i can do a native query to just add a result array to a choice fieldtype..

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just hardcode that? Actually, it's quite strange for an abstract class to know his exact childs.

You can manually inspect your entites and their annotations to build an inheritance tree in your bundle. But I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: I know it's strange behaviour, but in this case I need to know... And with hardcoding i have dubble administration....

Answer (score 0):

Just store the options somewhere. Either hardcode them like FractalizeR said, or put them in the database or in a file.

The abstract class shouldn't know about its subclasses